# Converting a date/time string to a date object

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a string:

```
"2014-07-30T21:11:35.6300000"
```

but when I do

```
new Date(str)
```

It computes:

> Wed Jul 30 2014 17:11:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Q: How do I tell JavaScript not to calculate GMT -0400?

Comment: "How do I tell JavaScript not to calculate GMT -0400?" --- what does it mean?

Comment: A JavaScript Date object just represents a point in time. By default when you print it, it prints it in your current locale... what are you trying to do with it where this is becoming a problem?

Comment: _Vanilla JavaScript's_ `Date` can give you _your local time_ (`.toString`), _GMT/UTC_ (`.toUTCString`), _ms since the unix epoch_ (`.valueOf`) and _ISO 8601_ (`.toISOString`)

Comment: I'm comparing it in another language, so when I save it as 21:11, it needs to say 21:11 and not be converted to 17:11.

Comment: @Phillip Sounds like you want to do all your work in _UTC_ then

Answer (score 1):

```
(new Date("2014-07-30T21:11:35.6300000")).toUTCString()
```